# How to easily figure out where and why a program crashed?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, codeblocks

I'm currently working on a program (in C++, using Code::Blocks) that uses a lot of random numbers and takes a while to get going; most of the time, it works fine, but every now and then it performs an illegal operation and must shut down.  Given the random numbers all over the place, and the fact that it currently takes ~3-5 minutes for the program to reach the stage at which the errors occur (this timeframe is normal/acceptable), reproducing the problems reliably and convenient is extremely difficult, and reporting on every other line of code to `cout` to manually track things is time-consuming, visually clutters reporting on things not related to bugs, and is not always helpful, since even if I know when the program stops, I sometimes don't know why.

Is there some way for me to see what the last operation in the program was before it crashed, and for me to see why this operation lead to a crash?  Something within CodeBlocks would be best, but something third-party works too.  It also needs to be something I can use every time I test the program, because I never know when a crash is going to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what debuggers are for. Build the system with full debugging symbols, configure the system so that you get a full crash report (in linux a core file), and then launch the debugger with the core file (alternatively run the whole program inside the debugger, but that might take a while, running inside a debugger is usually much slower than running outside of it.

The debugger should be able to give you the state of the program when the illegal instruction happened and you will get some insight as of the state that the program was on. From there either you figure what is wrong, or maybe you can make a couple of smaller testcases that might trigger the error.

Debugging issues that cannot be reproduced systematically is a pain, good luck there!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a debugger. [Debugging C and C++ programs using GDB](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/debugging/debugging-with-gdb.html)